# CloudFront caching - How to ensure CF refreshes from S3 origin server after expiry?

Tags: http, caching, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm putting assets to S3 with expiry headers, which successfully get passed through to CloudFront distributions. However, requests after the expiry don't result in CloudFront requesting a fresh file from the origin server.

I am also finding that query string version tokens don't force a fresh asset, and I don't want to use full, file name versioning.

All of this may be down to my poor knowledge of cache-control headers, but I am starting to wonder if I am missing something critical about how CloudFront is supposed to work. The CloudFront responses are showing headers like the following.

```
Cache-Control: max-age=120
Expires: Tue, 07 Apr 2009 12:13:26 GMT
```

Comment: I'm starting to look into this, and your finding that query string version tokens don't force a refresh are a bit concerning, I guess I could do a bunch of url rewriting but would prefer not to. (I'd be using it for generating variations of compressed and versioned CSS & JS from a single url with differing querystrings.)

Answer (score 9):

Time passes and things change.  As Tim had noted, the lowest cache time was 24hrs but in April 2010 Amazon announced that they will recognize and follow directives for caching down to an hour.

Announcement here: http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/ann.jspa?annID=655

Comment: And, come 2012, we're even further along: [no more minimum expiry time whatsoever](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/03/19/amazon-cloudfront-lowers-minimum-expiration-period/) :)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Amazon ignores expiry times less than 24 hours.
http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?messageID=107699&#107699

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments by Matchu, you can now set the expiry time all the way down to zero if you'd like, which is really nice for dev and testing servers!

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/03/19/amazon-cloudfront-lowers-minimum-expiration-period/

> The minimum TTL value may be as short as 0 seconds. You can then set the TTL for each file by setting the cache control header on your file in the origin.

Also note [what the Amazon docs say](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html):

> After the expiration date and time in the Expires header passes, CloudFront gets the object again from the origin server every time an edge location receives a request for the object.
>
> We recommend that you use the Cache-Control max-age directive instead of the Expires header field to control object caching. If you specify values both for Cache-Control max-age and for Expires, CloudFront uses only the value of max-age.